# Android share image Intent: WhatsApp - The file format is not supported

Tags: android, image, android-intent, share, whatsapp

I've problems with sharing images from my App to WhatsApp.

```
int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", "drawable", getPackageName());

Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.companyname.packagename/drawable/"+ imageId);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");                       
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

This code works fine with Facebook Messenger or Androids build in messenger. 
But it doesn't work with WhatsApp. I get this error message:

"The file format is not supported!"

> I've solved this problem by using @CommonsWare solution:
>   https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider

Comment: Many apps will have problems with `android.resource` `Uri` values, as they are uncommon, unexpected, and therefore frequently untested.

Comment: Try `shareIntent.setType("image/*");`

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your answer. Is there another way to get the path of my image file without using `android.resource` ?

Comment: You could move this drawable into `res/raw/` or `assets/`, then use my `StreamProvider` to serve it using a `content:` `Uri`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider Or, copy the image to a file on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), then [use `FileProvider` to serve it using a `content:` `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks :) I will try out your CWAC-Provider.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me even on Android 11. It based on this Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media. In my usecase, I needed to share an image generated from converting a layout to a bitmap. I had to first save the image to shared media storage but I believe private storage should work as as well.

```
public void shareImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Uri contentUri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
    } else {
        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    ContentValues newImageDetails = new ContentValues();
    newImageDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "filename");
    Uri imageContentUri = contentResolver.insert(contentUri, newImageDetails);

    try (ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =
                 contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(imageContentUri, "w", null)) {
        FileDescriptor fd = fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fd);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bufferedOutputStream);
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error saving bitmap", e);
    }

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageContentUri);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text here");
    sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share with");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In android 11 you need to use the file provider in order to share media files.

```
public void shareFile(){
   Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     sendIntent.setType("image/*");
     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", ImageUri));  
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Share "));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
//set your message
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msgText); 

String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image_name.jpg";

File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);

shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);`

try { // should you to check Whatsapp is installed or not
     startActivity(shareIntent)
}
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException exception) {
       showMessage("Whatsapp have not been installed")
}
```

Comment: Not Working in Android 11 (API level 30) . how to solve issue of File format not supported in Android R.

Comment: @SaurabhGaddelpalliwar have you found solution?

Comment: Yes I found the Solution

Comment: You Have to save Image on Android 11 Using below code   ,,  filesDir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),  ConstantString.IMAGE_FILE_SHARE_PATH_FULL); and  use this generated path to share image on WhatsApp.

Comment: Use This for Android 11 ,  String mediaPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mActivity.getContentResolver(), result, newFile.getName(), null);
                    imageInternalUri = Uri.parse(mediaPath);

Comment: Then pass this above Uri like this to share on whatsapp, ...  Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    waIntent.setType("image/*");
                    waIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageInternalUri);
                    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textYouWant);
                    mActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage() is deprecated now

Comment: @SaurabhGaddelpalliwar 's solution is only working.

Comment: @SaurabhGaddelpalliwar what is result insertImage() ????

Answer (score 0):

Replace `shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");`

with this `shareIntent.setType("image/*");` this will select all types of images and maybe this will work for you, because its workig for me just fine.

Answer (score -4):

```
mIntent.setType("image/png");
```

Replace with it this. It may work.

Comment: This doesn't work. If I use a png image and change the code to `shareIntent.setType("image/png");` , then the same error occurs.

Answer (score -5):

```
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
```

REPLACE BY `shareIntent.setType("image/*"); //it support all type of files.`

Comment: For all type of files you need shareIntent.setType(" * / * ").  no space between asterisks

Comment: This cannot be the solution, if I am sending an image only, and that too, a JPEG image.